# Pass a Row of a DataGrid to another wpf form c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have one wpf form with a `DataGrid` and another wpf form with `TextBoxes`.

I'm trying to pass each value of each cells of the selected row to the other form but i don't know how to do this with a wpf.

In the wpf Form2 i want to put these values into `TextBox` for edit and then update the row of the Form1 and so the connected `DataSet`.

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: How your data-model looks like ? What is your data-source for DataGrid looks like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using a `DataSet` for your `DataGrid`.

1. Get the selected row (`SelectedItem`) using `Binding`.
2. Send this ChosenItem as `ref` to the other form/window.
3. Set this sent `ChosenItem` as the `DataContext` of form grid.

Now, when you change the values in your Form2, changes will be reflected back in form1.

Eg code,

Form1

```
   <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenItem}" />            
        <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
    </Grid>
```

Form1 code-behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataStore ds = new DataStore();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Dgrid.DataContext = ds;
        Dgrid.ItemsSource = ds.DataSource.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView item = ds.ChosenItem;
        Window1 w = new Window1(ref item); // send selected row as ref to other form
        w.Show();
    }
}

   public class DataStore
   {
        public DataRowView ChosenItem { get; set; }

        public DataStore()
        {
            DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
            table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
            table1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));

            DataRow row = table1.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = "Name1";
            row["Address"] = "203 A";
            table1.Rows.Add(row);

            row = table1.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = "Deepak";
            row["Address"] = "BHEL Bhopal";
            table1.Rows.Add(row);

            ds.Tables.Add(table1);
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public DataSet DataSource { get { return ds; } }
    }
```

Form2

```
        <Grid x:Name="FormGrid" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Dgrid}">
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Address}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        </Grid>
```

Form2 code-behind

```
public Window1(ref DataRowView item)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FormGrid.DataContext = item;
}
```

Comment: In this scenario how can I update the DataGrid only when i click a Update Button? Because now if i edit the TexBoxes on the Form2, the Form1 is automatic update. But i want to wait to click an Update Button.